# Kindle PaperWhite as "paper replacement"

Tags: kindle, paperless

I am thinking of getting a Kindle as a kind of "paper replacement".  The idea is to have all my document in a "cloud" accessible from different devices.

To be useful, the Kindle would need to:

1. Be able to display common document formats, like pdf and word
2. Have some possibility to search the cloud.
3. Annotation and bookmarking.

Is this possible.  One problem is to get something "on to it".  But I think I could use a wireless hard drive.

One other problem is the small size, are there similar devices that are bigger or smarter?

Comment: Wow! It's like you came up with the EXACT same idea Amazon did! ;)

Comment: I used my Nexus 7 as a paper replacement. This syncs Drive without a problem and allows me to print a PDF directly to the device. Why not get a full tablet?

Comment: A Nexus 7 is at least twice the price of a Kindle Paperwhite, so price might well be a factor. Also the Kindle's battery lasts for about a month, reading every day. They're really nice devices, if all you want to do is read stuff.

Comment: "Why not get a full tablet" - I am comparing a reader + small smart color tablet to iPad Retina

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 basic ways to get things onto a Kindle:

- **USB** - once it's plugged into a PC, you can drag and drop stuff, use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), etc...
- **Email** - each Kindle has a unique email address, and you can email it attachments, which it will add to it's library
- **Buy from Amazon**, send to Kindle.

As far as I know, you can't copy things over directly via WiFi, except by using email or the Amazon store.

Kindles do support PDF (but the reading experience is *terrible*) but they don't support Word Documents, etc... These are your native format choices:

- .mobi - Mobipocket eBook format (.amz is a derivative of this)
- .pdf
- .txt

You can also use other formats by converting them to one of the supported formats. [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) will automatically convert [any files that it understands](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from) to the default Kindle format when you copy things across - and Amazons email service does some conversion too, at a cost:

> Amazon offers an email-based service that will convert GIF, PNG and BMP graphics to AZW.[101] Amazon will also convert HTML pages and Microsoft Word (DOC) or (DOCX) documents through the same email-based mechanism, which will send a Kindle-formatted file to the device via 3G for $0.15 per MB or via WiFi for free: [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle#File_formats)

There are lots of other e-Ink devices available, apart from Kindle, which may well be much more flexible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_e-book_readers

As for larger screens, e-Ink make a 9.7" screen, which is what the old Kindle DX used and is still available from some manufacturers.